# Connect SFTP in Dolphin with keyfile and passphrase and nonstandard port

Tags: ssh, dolphin, sftp

I am not finding an option to enter the keyfile when adding a network folder in Dolphin.

The "Add Network Folder" type is SSH. Dolphin allows me to enter a username, a server IP address, a port, the protocol (which is SFTP), and a folder. But Dolphin does not allow me to specify the SSH key. BTW, the SSH key requires a passphrase.

Can I make Dolphin work with an SSH key that requires a passphrase?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to add a custom host entry in your `~/.ssh/config` file, specifying the port, key file, and domain to use. Something like this, modified to have the values you need:

```
Host specialport
  HostName real.domain.com
  Port 50000
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/special-key_rsa.1
```

You can make the `specialport` value in there be whatever you want. Once you place that in the ssh config file, you can use that value as the hostname to connect to in Dolphin, like `sftp://specialport/home/` (if that is the URL scheme that Dolphin uses these days).

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. I found a little more info via `man ssh_config`.

Comment: Works for me too!

Comment: it should also be noted that the user to log in as can be specified in `User` directive in `~/.ssh/config` file or in the connection URL `sftp://user@host` on [tag:Dolphin].

Comment: This also allows you to SSH into the host simply with `ssh specialport` on CLI, FYI.